# iOS : how to launch app automatically

Tags: ios, passwords

I have a requirement where my app should launch automatically when user unlocks the phone (passcode).

I did some googling but that didn't help me much.

Comment: Is this for a jailbroken system?

Comment: no it is not specific for a jailbroken system.

Comment: Is this what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789352/ios-restricting-use-to-single-app

Comment: I have a requirement that my app should make me invisible.  Having requirements doesn't mean anything...

Comment: @borrrden : But atleast you should try other possibilities and not cry

Comment: by the way not only ur app but i also want you to go invisible

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible on iOS.

App can only be launched (i.e. enter in the foreground) from:

- Taping the icon
- A link in another app/web page using custom URL schemes
- A notification (User unlocking the phone from a received push notification)